# Failed to apply Patch on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to update my Android studio but I am getting this error message saying Failed to apply patch what Can i do to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: I have tried increasing the heap size to -Xm512m as specified in the video and I also tried increasing the heap size to -Xm700m still getting the issue! I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

1. Increase java heap capacity, [Windows 10 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-D24vnuUMM)

Hope that helps :)